# Upload file from input file to a folder using Visual Studio 2017 Asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on Visual Studio 2017 using Asp.net Mvc 5 to build a web site,My problem is that I can't upload an image from a input file to a server folder

MY CODE:

Create: Views

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Jobs",null,FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Jobs</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="upload"/>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "JobType", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( Jobs jobs,HttpPostedFile upload)
{            
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), FileName);
                upload.SaveAs(path);
                jobs.JobImage = FileName;
                db.Jobs.Add(jobs);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else{

            }                           
        }
    }
    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }





        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName", jobs.CategoryId);
        return View(jobs);
    }
```

when I click submit Button nothing change on browser and no error is generated, but when I check Uploads file I found nothing(img file ) ,the same on the database , I don't know where is the error

Note: 
Before I added the input file , my code was working perfectly

Any Help Please

Comment: Put breakpoint in your http post action method and see what line of code is being executed and what is not

Comment: When I remove the "if (ModelState.IsValid)"condition , it generate an error of NullReferenceException On line " string FileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);"